# ¿Cómo puedo incrementar un uint8 atómicamente?

Tags: go, atómico

Go tiene la biblioteca [atomic](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/) con los métodos `AddInt32` etc.  Pero si quiero incrementar un `int8`, `uint8`, `int16` o `uint16` atómaticamente, ¿cómo lo puedo hacer?

Principalmente me interesa la respuesta *más eficiente*, pero si hay otra forma menos eficiente, pero más corto, también me interesa.

Answer (score 1):

Actualmente no se puede realizar el incremento atómico de un entero menor a *32 bits*, al menos usando la librería estándar. Esto tiene que ver con la forma en la que están implementadas las instrucciones de *sync/atomic*, están hechas en ensamblador dependiendo de la arquitectura, las cuales trabajan con operandos de *32 y 64 bits*.

Para guardar *cualquier tipo* de forma atómica, se pueden utilizar los `atomic.Value` que proveen de las funciones `Load()` y `Store(v)` para acceder a un valor 'protegido' de forma atómica. Puedes ver un ejemplo [aquí](https://play.golang.org/p/0qni9Fa14a)

Comment: Como referencia puedes ver la implementación aquí https://golang.org/src/sync/atomic/asm_amd64.s

Comment: Aquí otras respuestas interesantes (en inglés) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36133364/are-reads-and-writes-for-uint8-in-golang-atomic

Comment: No pregunto como hacerlo necesariamente con la librería estándar. Seguramente es posible hacerlo, aun con mis códigos propios, ¿no?